# Using ArcPy to iterate through multiple LAZ files and convert them to LAS files with lastools

Tags: arcpy, convert, las, for-loop, syntaxerror

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks in ArcGIS Pro and I would like to convert multiple .laz files into .las files by using the opensource toolbox 'lastools' and its function 'laszip'. For this I would like to iterate through all files within my working directory by using a for-loop.

This is my code so far:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\user\lidar\laz" # Set the workspace
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\LAStools\LAStools\ArcGIS_toolbox\LAStools.tbx.tbx") # Import lastools

for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.laz"):
    outfile = arcpy.Describe(file).baseName + '_las' # Take original file name and add '_las'
    arcpy..laszip(input_file=file, 
                  only_report_size=False, also_compress_decompress_waveforms=False, 
                  output_format= "las",
                  output_file= r"C:\user\lidar\las\{}".format(outfile), # Define Output directory and and 'outfile' for file name
                  output_directory= r"C:\user\lidar\las", 
                  output_appendix="", additional_command-line_parameters="", verbose=True)
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\ast.py, in parse:
Line 35:    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 7)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I use the lastools toolbox in ArcPy?

Comment: Your `for` loop on the workspace string is completely wrong. It's going to iterate the characters of the string `['C',':','\\',...]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I adapted the code with the ListFIles() command (see above), but it still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: `arcpy..laszip` is invalid syntax, it would typically be `arcpy.toolboxalias.toolname()`

Comment: Hey I tried `arcpy.LAStools.laszip` but it also doesn't work. I also got the code examples by executing the function manually and by copying the python code (send to python), so this was proposed by ArcGIS itself.

Comment: Don't put your comment (`# Define Output directory and and 'outfile' for file name`) _within_ the function?

Comment: I would also suggest you continue to use `arcpy.LAStools.laszip`  as it helps with debugging and its crystal clear you are accessing a function called laszip from LAStools not some other custom toolbox.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions but it still doesn't work in python/Jupyter Notebook. Only if I'm executing  the function manually or also in the Model Builder it works, which is kind of odd to me.

Comment: Ditch the ending comma.   output_format= "las", should be  output_format= "las"

Comment: I tried it without the comma and it also didn't work. But I think the comma is correct to go to the next argument (it's all part of the laszip function).

Comment: Have you tried the Convert LAS tool in Pro? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/convert-las.htm

Comment: I tried it but I always get an error that the coordinate system is not definded. But it is, when I use lastools it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is still wondering how to make it work, this is one solotion I found [here](https://groups.google.com/g/lastools/c/tdtjxvSPnR8?pli=1). The problem was that the 'LAStools' toolbox can't be imported that easy into Arcpy. First a geoprocessing script has to be created. With this code I can run the 'laszip' function within a for-loop:

```
# set wd 
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\laz" 

# create geoprocessing script
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# import lastools by using the geoprocessing script
gp.AddToolbox(r"C:\Users\LAStools\ArcGIS_toolbox\LAStools.tbx")


for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.laz"):
    outfile = arcpy.Describe(file).baseName + '_las'
    print(outfile)
    arcpy.gp.laszip(file, 
                    False, 
                    False, 
                    "las", 
                    r"C:\Users\laz\las\{}".format(outfile),
                    r"C:\Users\laz\las", 
                    "", 
                    "", 
                    True)
```